# Is there a way to indicate that the errors in a quote are in the source material without using many '[sic]'s?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a quote has many errors in it, putting [*sic*] remarks will make the quote ugly and full of them. Is there a way to indicate that "all the errors are in the original material"?

For example, the quote:

> Hellow, can you tell with me in scype?

Will become

> Hellow[*sic*], can you tell[*sic*] with me in scype[*sic*]?

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comprehensive [Wkipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic) says that *sic* is the adverb "thus, so": *sic erat scriptum,* "thus it was written".

A single *sic* at the end of a quote would also suffice with that meaning, but it could be misinterpreted as referring only to the last mistake. An expression for "thus was it all written" would be useful. The Wikipedia article is unhelpful here.

The Latin for *all* in this case is *omne,* so one candidate is

> Hellow, can you tell with me in scype? [*sic omn.*]

That does presuppose a certain level of Latin in the reader, so an alternative might be

> Hellow, can you tell with me in scype? [all *sic*]

Answer (score 2):

If you're quoting a long sentence like that which has many errors, you can use one [sic] at the end

> Hellow, can you tell with me in scype? [sic]

would be adequate to use, as the reader will know the entire quoted part was direct from the source.